# How can you define the width of a container in % relatively to an element that is NOT its direct parent?

Tags: css, css-float, width

I have a header as follow: logo + nav containing 4  links
I would like to arrange all this element next to each other at the top (that is working), but also to make them at equal distance of each other. The second part does not work, I don't manage to define the size of the a elements in % ...

I am using float:left to position all this element on top next to each other. I am using the css property width to make them occupy 20% each of the total top of the page.

```
<body>
    <header>
      <a href="./index.html" class="logo"><img src="mylogo.png" style="width:42px;height:42px"></a>
      <nav>
        <a href="./index.html" class="welcome active">Welcome</a>
        <a href="./about.html" class="about">About</a>
        <a href="./artwork.html" class="artwork">Art Work</a>
        <a href="./events.html" class="events">Events</a>
       </nav>
     </header>
     <h1>Title of the page</h1>
</body>
```

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}

nav {
    float: left;
}

nav a {
    width: 20%;
}
```

There is some space between the logo and the links, but the links does not arrange along the top at equal distance, they stay stuck to each other... I suppose it's because their width is relative to nav, which is not 100% as there is the logo. But I don't know how to define the size of these a elements relatively to the header that I fixed to be 100% of my page?

Comment: make the width of nav `80%`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. I made some changes in your css and instead of float I used flex-box technique to align them. I made the header black to detect the header easily. You can change it in the css. Hope this solution will help you.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

header {
    height: 10vw;
    line-height: 10vw;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
}

.logo img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: inherit;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: inherit;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    transition: all .33s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
      <a href="./index.html" class="logo"><img src="mylogo.png" style="width:42px;height:42px"></a><!-- --><a href="./index.html" class="welcome active">Welcome</a><!-- --><a href="./about.html" class="about">About</a><!-- --><a href="./artwork.html" class="artwork">Art Work</a><!-- --><a href="./events.html" class="events">Events</a>
       
     </header>
     <h1>Title of the page</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks @Showrin Barua, it's not exactly what I want as the elements are still not at equal distance from each other (there is bigger space between the logo and the links), but I will investigate this display:flex, it seems to possibly lead to a solution.

Comment: @JääßJääß welcome. But I still don't understand what you want ('_') .

Comment: That the logo, and each links are on top at equal distance. Let's say that  -- equals is 40px:
Border left of the browser I -- Logo -- Welcome -- About -- Art Work -- Events -- I Border right of the browser

Comment: May be I've understood. I just made another edit in my answer. Please check it.

Comment: No actually I want something like this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_topnav_equal_width.asp
But the problem is that when I add the logo it does not work, I must setting something wrong with the width I assume, or maybe the fact that there is both an a + nav a in the hearder breaks it

Comment: @JääßJääß Check the answer. I made a new edit. Hope it is what you want.

Comment: Thank you! :) Yes, that's what I wanted :) I also found another solution, I post it as an answer (so that maybe it formats the code better than in a comment)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the following CSS worked:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}

header nav {
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
}

header nav a {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```